# How does this site import the content using jQuery UI tabs?

Tags: jquery, rss, jquery-tabs, ning

Site: http://www.friendsorenemies.com/

That site has jQuery UI tabs set up with *Features*, *VIP Blogs*, and *All*. But how are they importing the content? Originally, I was thinking I could use a jQuery rss parser like zRSSFeed, but realized that the blog author avatars don't show in rss feeds nor does meta data like this below:

`Posted By authorname | 1 Comment | May 6, 2011 | 5:39pm`

Then, I thought maybe they are using iFrames? But I looked at the source code and they are not.

You can see that:

- the *Features* tab is getting the content from [this page](http://www.friendsorenemies.com/profiles/blog/list?promoted=1).
- the *VIP Blogs* tab is getting the content from [this page](http://www.friendsorenemies.com/vip/blog/list?promoted=1).
- the *All* tab is getting the content from [this page](http://www.friendsorenemies.com/profiles/blog/list).

Anybody have an idea? This has been driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're just using the Tabs widget's [AJAX feature](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax).

jQuery UI will automagically load content via AJAX when you give a "real" link in the `a` tag for a tab.

Comment: Do you mean adding the page link in the `a` tag (e.g. http://bit.ly/kqkLL7)? If so, wouldn't it import the whole page and not just the blog section?

Comment: If you look at the source, you'll see that the links they're using are not the same as the ones you posted. They have a different URLs that display just the bare content for each of those pages, and the tabs use those URLs.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If you don't mind, I would really appreciate it if you can point out exactly where in the source these links are. I must have looked it over about a hundred times. Would you mind?